# Merge fields in pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I have two columns "ID_TT" in select values 1 and "ID_ARC" in select values 2.

ID_TT has below values

[blank]

121

[blank]

ID_ARC has below values

146

[blank]

171

I need to merge these two . I used calculator but it does not work. How can we solve this.

output must be

146

121

171

[image]

Comment: Don't understand. Does it have to be that specific order? Are you grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.  I think its useful to you

[image]

If  you follow above step you can get that result like these.

Result:

[image]

Thank you.